# Listview generating SQL data slowly, SQL queries in 1 sec, where generating data in listview takes 15+ seconds

Tags: sql, vb.net, t-sql

How can I optimize this code to generate the data in the list view faster? The SQL query takes < 1 second to execute, but this code takes 15 seconds plus

```vb
Dim connn As SqlClient.SqlConnection
Dim cmdd As SqlClient.SqlCommand
Dim da As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim itemcoll(100) As String

If NameComboBox.Text = "" Then
    Me.JobList.Clear()
    Me.JobList.View = View.Details
    connn = New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server Connection")
    Dim strQ As String = String.Empty
    strQ = "SELECT  Customer, job, Convert(Date, seals, 121) as [Complete]
    FROM Database Inner Join Job2 on Job1.jobref = Job2.jobreflink  
    WHERE [job] <> '' and seals <> '' and seals >= '1/1/2017' Order by jobnumber desc;"
    cmdd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(strQ, connn)
    da = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmdd)
    ds = New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "Table")
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim j As Integer = 0
    For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
    Me.JobList.Columns.Add(ds.Tables(0).Columns(i).ColumnName.ToString())
    Next
    For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
         For j = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
             itemcoll(j) = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(j).ToString()
         Next
         itemcoll(j) = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(j).ToString()
         Me.JobList.Items.Add(lvi)
    Next
End If
```

Comment: This is what happens when you don't bother to read the documentation. The documentation for the `ListView` says that you should not add multiple items one by one like that but rather create them all first and then add them all with a single call to `AddRange`. The problem is that the `ListView` redraws itself after each item is added and that is slow and gets slower as the number of items increases. The alternative to calling `AddRange` is to `BeginUpdate` before your loop and `EndUpdate` afterwards, to turn off that drawing while adding items.

Comment: By the way, you really shouldn't be using a `ListView` here in the first place if you're not either grouping or using multiple views. Otherwise, you should just populate a `DataTable` and bind it to a `DataGridView`. The `ListView` is not a grid control.

Comment: To be precise, before it's pointed out, the documentation for the `ListView` class does not specify that `AddRange` should be used, although it does use it in a code example. It's actually the documentation for the `Add` method that says to use `AddRange` or `Add` with `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate`. In this case, you were using the `Add` method and it wasn't producing the behaviour you wanted so reading the documentation for that method should have been one of the first things you did. That's an important lesson for any beginner to learn.

Comment: Yeah I have seen that across a lot of forums, I am just stuck on how to use addrange, as I am looking for a similar example somewhere online if they are using sql data as well

Comment: Creating a `ListViewItem` with data is the same whether that data is hard-code, read from a text file, retrieved from a database or whatever. Do you need to change how you bake a cake depending on where the ingredients come from? The principle is simple: create the items and add them to a collection, then add the whole collection to the `ListView`. You obviously know how to do the first part because you're already doing it. You just have to use a collection other than the `Items` of the `ListView`. As I'm sure plenty of examples show, create a `List(Of ListViewitem)`.

Answer (score 1):

why not use 
`Listbox1.items.addrange` 
rather than using oly add.?? it'll be a lot faster

Comment: How would you go about doing that since addrange method only accepts Arrays where as I am using a Dataset?

Comment: That you're using a `DataSet` is irrelevant. `AddRange` accepts an array of `ListViewItem` objects and your code demonstrates that you already know how to create `ListViewItem` objects from your `DataSet`. You simply need to `Add` those objects to a collection other than the `Items` of the `ListView`, then call `ToArray` on that collection to get your array. It just took me 30 seconds to find an example of exactly that with a web search for "vb.net listview addrange" so I have to question how hard you've tried.

Comment: This is why everyone should read [ask] and should do some researching about the problem before posting.....and i don't need to say much as @jmcilhinney has explained everything